# Inequality between Finite Sum of Reciprocals and Finite Euler product formula using Square-free Factor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divergent-series, euler-product

The Wikipedia page on the divergence of the sum of reciprocals of primes has a proof of the log log divergence rate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Proof_that_the_series_exhibits_log-log_growth

It starts with the following inequality:

$$\sum_i^n \frac{1}{i} \leq \prod_{p\leq n}(1+\frac{1}{p}) \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$$

The inequality is stated as obvious but it isn't to me and those I've asked.

Can anyone explain the inequality?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ on the left side?

Comment: Every number less than $n$ can be written as a square times the product of distinct primes, each less than $n$.

Comment: @IPPK thanks, corrected

Comment: @lulu - is the inequality because the numbers that constructed by "square times the product of distinct primes, each less than $n$" can be greater than $n$? I'm struggling with the inequality.

Comment: No.  Every term on the left is of the form $\frac 1m$ for some $m≤n$.  Now, we can write $m=p_1p_2\cdots p_j k^2$ for some $k≤n$ and each $p_i$ a prime less than $n$.  All such expressions appear on the right.

Comment: @Lulu - thanks, but why is the relation $\leq$ and not $=$ ?

Comment: Because there are some terms on the right which are not on the left.  For instance $\frac 1{n^2}$.

Comment: I think this would all be clearer to you if you just wrote it out for some small $n$.  Let $n=4$, say.  So the primes involved are just $p\in \{2,3\}$.Just write out the right hand completely in that case.  Working with examples is always a good way to start.

Comment: @Lulu - Your comment on "m=..." and the other comment that some terms don't appear the right forms an answer, if you wanted to add it as one.